# Having two instances of Context Factory under the same JVM

Tags: javascript, java, jvm, rhino

I'm using [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/) to compile and execute javascript functions. In order to constrain the execution time of scripts, I created a custom [ContextFactory](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/ContextFactory.html#call(org.mozilla.javascript.ContextAction)) where am able to set the max cpu time allowed and the number of instructions before calling [observeInstructionCount](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/ContextFactory.html#observeInstructionCount(org.mozilla.javascript.Context,%20int)), similarly to the example described in [ContextFactory](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/ContextFactory.html#call(org.mozilla.javascript.ContextAction)).

The following code is a sample of the method I use to compile and execute the functions.

```
CustomFactory factory = new CustomFactory().setMaxCpuTime(300L);
if (!ContextFactory.hasExplicitGlobal()) {
            ContextFactory.initGlobal(factory );
}
Context context = factory.enterContext();
Scriptable Scope = context.initStandardObjects();
Function function = context.compileFunction(scope, script, "<func>", 0, null);
(...)
function.call(context, scope, scope, args);
```

Every thing works as excepted, the scripts that exceed the maximum allowed cpu time throw an Error. My problem is that I want to have two instances of my custom factory under the same JVM, one that will allow the scripts to run for a little longer than the other. But because of the call **ContextFactory.initGlobal(factory)**  every Context will inherit the same ContextFactory. Even if I create a new custom factory with a different allowed cpu time, when I call **factory.enterContext()** the context will inherit the factory that was passed to **initGlobal**.

Is there any way to have two instances of ContextFactory (with different properties) under the same JVM?